# \n not putting text on a new line in php error_log function

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging

I'm trying to get my errors in my error.log file to be on separate lines, but \n does not seem to be doing that. I feel like i'm missing something easy, but it's all on the same line so if i have a bunch of errors in there it will be almost impossible to find them.

```
<?php

$msg_one = "Error message 1.\n ";
$msg_two = "Error message 2.\n ";

$log_file = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\logging\\errors.log";

error_log($msg_one, 3, $log_file); 
error_log($msg_two, 3, $log_file);

?>
```

and the output in the log file looks like this:

```
Error message 1. Error message 2.
```

Comment: Windows, could you try `"\r\n"`? Or better yet, the `PHP_EOL` constant? On a side note: I prefer to use `trigger_error` instead, which just follows standard `error_reporting` / `log_errors` / `display_errors` config out of the box, so I only have to configure that differently for development & production, without having to have different code in dev of productation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`

```
<?php

$msg_one = "Error message 1.\r\n ";
$msg_two = "Error message 2.\r\n ";

$log_file = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\logging\\errors.log";

error_log($msg_one, 3, $log_file); 
error_log($msg_two, 3, $log_file);

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The text prints the message with \n and the \r is gone, and any text afterwards will be on the same line.

Comment: found the issue (requires all double quotes everywhere)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978290/how-to-log-object#answer-56070721